# Websockets severe delay/latency

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, websocket, uwebsockets

We're using websockets (specifically uws.js on Node.js) to run a multiplayer quiz. The server's running on an AWS t2.micro in the eu-west-2a region, but recently, we've been seeing some incredibly high latency from some players - yet only on an intermittent basis.

By latency, what I'm actually measuring is the time taken from sending a broadcast message (using uws's built in pub-sub), to the player's device telling the server they've safely received it. The message we're tracking tells the player's device to move on to the next phase of the quiz, so it's pretty critical to the workings of the application. Most of the time, for players in the UK, this time is somewhere around 30 - 60 ms, but every now and then we're seeing delays of up to 17s.

Recently, we had a group on the other side of the world to our server do a quiz, and even though there were only 10 or so players, so the server's definitely not being overloaded, we saw roughly half that group intermittently getting these very, very high latency spikes, where it'd take 12, 17, 22, or even 39(!!) seconds for their device to acknowledge having received the message. Even though this is a slow paced quiz, that's still an incredibly amount of latency, and something that has a real detrimental effect.

My question is, how do I tell what's causing this, and how do I fix it? My guess would be it's something to do with TCP and its in-order delivery, combined with some perhaps dodgy internet connections, as one of the players yesterday seemed to receive nothing for 39 seconds, then three messages all in a row, backed up. To me that suggests packet loss, but I don't know where to even begin when trying to resolve it. I also haven't yet figured out how to reproduce it (I've never seen it happen when I've been playing myself), which makes things even harder.

Answer (score 0):

TCP routing issues are unlikely to cause extreme delays of 17+seconds. Are you sure there is no "store and forward" queuing system that is buffering your messages on a server or perhaps a cloud pub/sub queue?

Another important check: t2.micro is just about the cheapest, least-assured networking QoS VM you can boot on AWS. No throughput and no jitter assurances on the network performance.
You may wish to review:

1. [EC2 network benchmarking guide from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/) including MTU parameters
2. [Available instance bandwidth for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html)

t2.micro does not have any minimum baseline assured bandwidth for example.

Comment: Hi Sid, thanks for the reply. I'm pretty sure there's no buffering or pub/sub issues. When the incident happened above, we only had 10 people on the server - and to further piece things together, I managed to recreate the issue yesterday when I was literally the only one on the server. 

I think my WiFi must have been playing up at the time, as I used Wireshark to sniff things out, and was seeing a lot of TCP retransmissions and duplicate ACKs, with latencies reported on the server of up to around about 12-ish seconds, so not too far off the example before.

Comment: Very interesting. I have edited my answer to add some EC2 checklists and network QoS guidance.